# @font-face Generator, pages in sub-folders do not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-face

Having a weird issue using Font Squirrel's font generator. I follwed the steps and have it all working in all broswers.

However as soon as I make a new folder and copy across the index file, and alter the CSS root, the new page does not work, but the original does. This is only happening in Firefox 3.6, all other browsers render the new page correctly (i.e. /test/index.html).

To replicate the issue, generate a font using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator, and then unzip the files, create a new folder and copy across the demo.html to the new folder and amend the CSS path.

Is this a common issue?

Comment: If the test is available on the web, can you provide full URLs? If not, please provide us steps how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the bug as well. I chalk this up to a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the answer thanks to a [french forum post](http://forum.alsacreations.com/topic-4-73076-1-Resolu-Jai-perdu-ma-font-en-deplacant-une-page.html#lastofpage) i folowed this morning.

This is only a **LOCAL** issue due to the [security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy) param of Firefox. The documentation says that :

***True** : Local documents have access to other local documents in the same directory and in subdirectories, but not directory listings. (Default)*

***False** : Local documents have access to all other local documents, including directory listings.*

***Recommended settings** : If you do development with local files and need to be able to retrieve other local files, you may need to set this preference to false. Otherwise, leaving it set to true offers the most security.*

In order to fix that on your environment :

- type **about:config** in the FF url bar (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration)
- find the **security.fileuri.origin_policy** option
- set it to **false** by double-click it
- **reboot** FF